# Parse Server - Where does it store uploaded files

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, parse-server

I am new to Parse Server (implementing it on Heroku and locally).

I have a basic question, when I upload a file using the ParseFile class, it provides me a URL and a fileobject. Where is this File being stored?

Is it being stored physically on a file system? Or in Mongodb?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a collection in Mongodb named fs.files. The files I uploaded were located there. I assume the Parse URL is generated as a redirect.

Comment: I've seen the fs.files that you're talking about. But there is only the meta data about these files.
Moreover, I have 200 files (their size should be 4 mb all together), but the `fs.files`'s is only 70 KB.

Edit: I can see fs.chunks which weights 8 mb, still strange but makes more logic... And I also can only see in the `data` field in each row: `"<Binary Data>"`